# The value none is being returned Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, oop, fibonacci

I'm completely confused as to why my code is returning none. I'm new and have been searching for a while and i'm still lost.

```
class Fibonacci:

    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max: # if n is less that 0
            def FIB(number):
                if number == 1 or number == 2:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return FIB(number - 1) + FIB(number - 2)
            self.n += 1
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: You never call the `FIB` function you defined. Below the `self.n += 1` line, add `return FIB(self.n)`

Comment: What are you calling where you're code is returning `None`. I don't see any method's other than dunder's?

Comment: @rafaelc Thank you! I have been staring at this for way longer than i should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation spends more and more time every time you call `__next__`. should have used an iterative method instead with the constant complexity of iteration over it:

```
class Fibonacci:

    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        if self.a <= self.max: # if n is less that 0
            return self.a
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```